# GeneralDetailReportQuery key field

Tags: sql-server, quickbooks

We use GeneralDetailReportQuery to get customer "transactions" from QuickBooks desktop and save them to a mssql table. Query is called passing the From/To Date filter params to get changes only. We try to get report changes each day and keep our table in sync with QB data. TranId, customer ListId and TranType seem to be those fields which can uniquely identify each record returned by Report query. Problem starts to happen when users change one of those key fields, customer ListId for example.
It must have been a change of a customer in a transaction... ?
Anyway, how to keep data in sync, does report have some kind of primary key field, which is not changed and can be use to track changes ?

Thanks,

Slava